# Mongoose populate with type String

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I am trying to populate "category" to the "Category" model
using **type:String** to match **_id:String** in the category schema
but it return "null"

Am I using it the wrong way?

category.js and product.js
[image: category.js and product.js]

index.js
[image: index.js]

postman result
[image: postman]

product data in mongoDB
[image: data in mongoDB]

Comment: try to give field names to populate: `.populate('category', '_id parent ancestors')`

Comment: The `category` field in the `products` document you show in the last screenshot is an embedded document, not just a reference. So your schema doesn't match up.